# nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'tagId' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]

Tags: mybatis

map.xml :
 
    SELECT
    
    FROM channel_dynamic
    where tag_id = #{tagId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    and article_id = #{articleId,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
  
Dao:
   ChannelDynamic selectByTypeAnd(@Param(value = "tagId" )Long tagId,@Param(value = "articleId") String articleId);

but run has error
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'tagId' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved:

The reason  the annotation is wrong ，should use the @parame of mybits, and I use the @param in spring

Answer (score 0):

I agree that OP's answer.
Here is correct import name:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
```

DO NOT USE

```
import io.lettuce.core.dynamic.annotation.Param;
```